# How to wrap text inside new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapper, gettext

My HTML:

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div class="innerDiv">This is a div</div>
  This is what I want to wrap
</div>
```

What I want:

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <div class="innerDiv">This is a div</div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    This is what I want to wrap
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried:

```
$('.mainDiv').find(".innerDiv").next().wrap('<div class="wrapper" />')
```

but it does not work. How can I achieve above result?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) along with [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
$('.mainDiv').contents().slice(-1).wrap('<div class="wrapper"/>');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/duDmZ/)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using `nextSibling`:

```
$($('.mainDiv .innerDiv')[0].nextSibling).wrap('<div class="wrapper">');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4MCen/

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution

```
$('.mainDiv').contents().last().wrap('<div class="wrapper"/>');
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/VTDHL/)